# Espresso + Junit4 How to test on other screens that require login

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I started learning Espresso couple days ago,and found it very nice library for testing but i stuck on a problem.

I want to test "Home screen" but before moving to home screen User should be logged-in as i get many details from server and stored in my shared preferences.

So i found "@Before" Annotation that can be used.

But drawback of @Before annotation is that it will execute before every test method. in case if i have four test cases are written then it will be execute four times. That should not be done.

Then i googled again and found "@BeforeClass" annotation can be used that is called once while class is started as per given link ([Espresso + Junit4 - login once before running all test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850656/espresso-junit4-login-once-before-running-all-test))

But it didn't solve my problem as login activity is not started in "below" method with "@BeforeClass" annotation

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
    // do login stuff here
}
```

**So what should i do as i require login information before executing test cases for home screen.
Below is the code i am testing**

Any help will he appreciated...
Thanks in advance

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

@Before
public void setUp() {
    onView(withId(R.id.et_username_login))
            .perform(typeText(Credentials.USERNAME), ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.et_password_login))
            .perform(typeText(Credentials.PASSWORD), ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.btn_login)).perform(click());
}
@Test
public void onAllEventTabTest() {
    onView(withId(R.id.ll_tab_1)).perform(click());
}

@Test
public void formPacketTabTest() {
    onView(withId(R.id.ll_tab_2)).perform(click());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which activity you want to launch through the ActivityTestRule

If you're **already logged in** use the **rule for your other activity** to test like

```
@Rule
public final android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> main = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);
```

It should go directly to it without the need to login.